# Elasticsearch - get results for autocomplete only for start of words

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I'm using elasticsearch to give autosuggestions on a search bar but I want it to match only the beginning of words. Eg.

```
doc_name_1 = "black bag"
doc_name_2 = "abla bag"
```

Case 1.
On search bar string is `part_string = "bla"` the query I'm currently using is

```
query_body = {"query": {
            "match": {
                "_all": {
                    "query": part_string,
                    "operator": "and",
                    "type": "phrase_prefix"

                }
            }
    }}
```

this query returns hits on `doc_name_1` and `doc_name_2`.

What I need is to get only hit on `doc_name_1` since `doc_name_1` does not start the same way as the string queried.
I tried using `"type":"phrase"` but ES keeps going "inside" the words in the docs. Is it possible to do that just by modifying the query? or settings?

I'll share my ES settings:

```
{ "analysis":{
                "filter":{
                    "nGram_filter": {
                        "type": "ngram",
                        "min_gram": 1,
                        "max_gram":20,
                        "token_chars": [
                            "letter",
                            "digit",
                            "punctuation",
                            "symbol"
                        ]
                }},
                "analyzer":{
                    "nGram_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter":[
                            "lowercase",
                            "asciifolding",
                            "nGram_filter"
                        ]
                    },
                    "whitespace_analyzer": {
                        "type":"custom",
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "asciifolding"
                        ]
                }}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [edge n-gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) instead of n-gram. you are breaking up the text from all postions of the word and filling the inverted index against lookup.

Comment: I'm trying to use the edge n-gram but should I add it in the settings along with the n-gram analyzer or INSTEAD of it? getting this error  "Analyzer [nGram_analyzer] not found for field [_all]"

Comment: sorry, solved the issue in the last comment, it had to do with mapping the documents.

Comment: yeah you have to upload new settings and then upload new mappings and reindex all your documents again to the ES.